In Monopoly, when I buy a hotel, can I buy the houses back from the bank straight away and use them on my other property?
I want to buy a hotel after having 4 houses on a property. Can I buy the houses back straight away and use them on another of my properties?

Yes, you can do this. After you have bought your hotel, there's nothing different or special about the situation compared to just wanting to buy houses normally.
Note that if another player also wishes to purchase houses at the same time as you, then the limited available houses will be auctioned, you don't get priority just because it is your turn.If there are a limited number of houses and hotels available and two or more players wish to buy more than the Bank has, the houses or hotels must be sold at auction to the highest bidder.

If there are a limited number of houses and hotels available and two or more players wish to buy more than the Bank has, the houses or hotels must be sold at auction to the highest bidder.


Thank you that’s so helpful and insightful . I thought as much but wanted to check.

You're welcome. Best way to thank someone on this site is to use the check mark to mark the answer as "accepted".
